Blob shape effect (SVG or Canvas)

I'm working on similar functionality using react-native-svg. I’ve created a sample, but it doesn’t look quite right. Could someone please take a look and suggest any plugins or approaches? I have over 70+ blob shapes to work with, and I would really appreciate any help.
Let me explain more. I have an SVG of a blob shape (as shown purple shape in the attached GIF). When someone clicks on the chart icon and expands it, I want to display a bubble effect (also shown in the attached GIF).
The challenge I'm facing is creating the bubble effect without disturbing the other parts of the SVG.
"use client";

import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Heart, Star } from "lucide-react";

const MIN_STRETCH = -10; // Minimum stretch value
const MAX_STRETCH = 20;  // Maximum stretch value

export default function BubbleStretchySVG() {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);
  const [stretchedPath, setStretchedPath] = useState("");
  const [activeSection, setActiveSection] = useState(null);
  const [initialMousePos, setInitialMousePos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  const originalPath =
    "M67.0119 29.251C63.1708 28.0979 54.9124 25.7917 54.9124 25.7917C54.9124 25.7917 29.5608 20.6027 19.766 29.251C9.97113 37.8992 0.199407 56.3488 1.05202 63.2674C1.7181 68.6723 3.46558 72.6983 5.66144 77.6812C8.13114 83.2854 6.79885 87.1839 11.1234 91.5184C13.826 94.2272 16.6508 93.9096 19.766 96.1308C24.9554 99.8311 24.7316 106.04 30.7132 108.238C35.1488 109.868 38.0904 108.4 42.8128 108.238C51.8527 107.929 62.2105 108.431 65.8596 105.932C69.5087 103.434 76.3651 98.7064 76.8068 97.8605C77.2485 97.0146 79.4956 90.7497 80.84 87.4826C82.1844 84.2154 87.2545 81.5017 89.4826 76.5281C91.9038 71.1234 86.5611 64.3186 91.7872 61.5378C96.1215 59.2316 107.261 64.4205 111.678 62.6909C116.095 60.9612 123.778 59.2316 125.781 55.1957C125.781 55.1957 130.598 48.5315 132.419 43.6647C134.423 38.3093 135 32.7103 135 29.251C135 25.7917 131.066 8.78295 120.319 4.4593C115.292 2.43656 112.166 2.6246 106.768 2.1531C101.816 1.72061 98.4262 1 94.0919 1C89.7577 1 82.2952 6.14371 76.8068 11.9545C71.4774 17.5969 70.8531 30.4041 67.0119 29.251Z";

  const handleIconMouseDown = (e, sectionIndex) => {
    setActiveSection(sectionIndex);
    const svg = svgRef.current;
    if (svg) {
      const svgRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
      setInitialMousePos({
        x: (e.clientX - svgRect.left) / (svgRect.width / 136),
        y: (e.clientY - svgRect.top) / (svgRect.height / 110),
      });
    }
  };

const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (activeSection === null || !svgRef.current) return;

    const svg = svgRef.current;
    const svgRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouseX = (e.clientX - svgRect.left) / (svgRect.width / 136);
    const mouseY = (e.clientY - svgRect.top) / (svgRect.height / 110);

    let newPath = originalPath;

    if (activeSection === 0) {
        // Stretch bottom-left section downwards
        const deltaY = mouseY - initialMousePos.y;
        const stretchY = Math.max(MIN_STRETCH, Math.min(MAX_STRETCH, deltaY)); // Constrain within limits

        newPath = newPath.replace(
            /30.7132 108.238C35.1488 109.868/, 
            `30.7132 ${108.238 + stretchY}C35.1488 ${109.868 + stretchY}`
        );
    } else if (activeSection === 1) {
        
        // Stretch star icon's bubble section
        const deltaX = mouseX - initialMousePos.x;
        const deltaY = mouseY - initialMousePos.y;

        const stretchX = Math.max(MIN_STRETCH, Math.min(MAX_STRETCH, deltaX)); // Constrain within limits
        const stretchY = Math.max(MIN_STRETCH, Math.min(MAX_STRETCH, deltaY)); // Constrain within limits

        newPath = newPath.replace(
          /111.678 62.6909C116.095 60.9612 123.778 59.2316 125.781 55.1957C125.781 55.1957 130.598 48.5315 132.419 43.6647C134.423 38.3093 135 32.7103 135 29.251C135 25.7917 131.066 8.78295 120.319 4.4593C115.292 2.43656 112.166 2.6246 106.768 2.1531C101.816 1.72061 98.4262 1 94.0919 1C89.7577 1 82.2952 6.14371 76.8068 11.9545C71.4774 17.5969 70.8531/,
          `${111.678 + stretchX} ${62.6909 + stretchY}C${116.095 + stretchX} ${60.9612 + stretchY} ${123.778 + stretchX} ${59.2316 + stretchY} ${125.781 + stretchX} ${55.1957 + stretchY}C${125.781 + stretchX} ${55.1957 + stretchY} ${130.598 + stretchX} ${48.5315 + stretchY} ${132.419 + stretchX} ${43.6647 + stretchY}C${134.423 + stretchX} ${38.3093 + stretchY} ${135 + stretchX} ${32.7103 + stretchY} ${135 + stretchX} ${29.251 + stretchY}C${135 + stretchX} ${25.7917 + stretchY} ${131.066 + stretchX} ${8.78295 + stretchY} ${120.319 + stretchX} ${4.4593 + stretchY}C${115.292 + stretchX} ${2.43656 + stretchY} ${112.166 + stretchX} ${2.6246 + stretchY} ${106.768 + stretchX} ${2.1531 + stretchY}C${101.816 + stretchX} ${1.72061 + stretchY} ${98.4262 + stretchX} ${1 + stretchY} ${94.0919 + stretchX} ${1 + stretchY}C${89.7577 + stretchX} ${1 + stretchY} ${82.2952 + stretchX} ${6.14371 + stretchY} ${76.8068 + stretchX} ${11.9545 + stretchY}C${71.4774 + stretchX} ${17.5969 + stretchY} ${70.8531 + stretchX}`
        );
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        setStretchedPath(newPath);
    });
};

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setActiveSection(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleGlobalMouseUp = () => {
      setActiveSection(null);
    };

    window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleGlobalMouseUp);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleGlobalMouseUp);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen bg-gray-100">
      <svg
        ref={svgRef}
        width="408"
        height="330"
        viewBox="-50 -50 408 330" // Adjusted viewBox to provide more play area
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      >
        <path d={stretchedPath || originalPath} stroke="#B4A1DE" strokeWidth="2" fill="transparent" />

        {/* Bottom-left icon */}
        <g
          transform="translate(20, 90)"
          className="cursor-pointer"
          onMouseDown={(e) => handleIconMouseDown(e, 0)}
        >
          <circle r="15" fill="#B4A1DE" />
          <foreignObject x="-9" y="-9" width="18" height="18">
            <Heart size={18} color="#FFFFFF" />
          </foreignObject>
        </g>

        {/* Top-right icon */}
        <g
          transform="translate(100, 30)"
          className="cursor-pointer"
          onMouseDown={(e) => handleIconMouseDown(e, 1)}
        >
          <circle r="15" fill="#B4A1DE" />
          <foreignObject x="-9" y="-9" width="18" height="18">
            <Star size={18} color="#FFFFFF" />
          </foreignObject>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}



Please provide some code so others can make adjustments to it, to help you achieve your desired output.

@JaromandaX check the code now

@Beast80k check the code now

@JaromandaX in gif when curser click the shape and shape had expend that effect i want to build

@JaromandaX can i send you meet link ?
